# What is the purpose of 'n = n'?

Tags: fortran

I am reading some Fortran code, and every so often the previous programmer throws in the statement 'n = n'. What is the purpose of this? Some example code:

```
if (cmult.lt.5.) then
    kx = 0
    do k=ipd(ii),lpd(ii)
       kx = kx + 1
       p1(kx) = epp_rfc(ipp,k)
       epp_rfc(ipp,k) = cmult*epp_rfc(ipp,k) + x   
       zero(ix)
       p2(kx) = epp_rfc(ipp,k)
       n = n
    enddo

if (cmult.gt.0.) then
    n = n
endif

else
    nk = lpd(ii) - ipd(ii) + 1
    do k=ipd(ii),lpd(ii)
       kx = kx + 1
       p1(kx) = epp_rfc(ipp,k)
       epp_rfc(ipp,k) = pp(imem) + zero(ix)
       p2(kx) = epp_rfc(ipp,k)
       n = n
    enddo
endif
```

Answer (score 14):

Code like this is frequently used to allow the programmer to set a breakpoint in debuggers that don't support conditional breakpoints.

By setting a breakpoint on that line, it will only be hit if `cmult.gt.0.`

Comment: How did you know this? That's very interesting.

Comment: +1, @tofutim most FORTRAN debuggers aren't as nice as .Net ones, so lots of these "hacks" are common. I've seen these constructs in most languages where `write` / `printf` debugging is common.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that `n = n` is used for checking the value of `cmult.gt.0.` and is used as 'condition breakpoint' is coincidental in a sense that it's not the reason why n = n appears in the above code snippet.

The real reason why n = n is used in this case lies in the fact that scope in the source code is never translated by the most popular compilers to assembly language (the computer is not smart enough to understand what 'scope' is unless its explicitly programmed by the programmer and if it did the programs will run 100s of time slower ... because of the extra instructions emitted for the logic to support scoping). It's only there to constraint the programmer in the source code and introduce a structure to the code so that linker & compiler can do their job - or issue error if violate scoping.

Because scope doesn't exist `enddo` cannot be paused at unless the comipler takes care to insert some instruction(like nop) and debug symbols for it to magically allow the debugger to stop at `enddo`. Without n = n the outcome of this line `p2(kx) = epp_rfc(ipp,k)` cannot be checked as the values reset at the top of the loop. This is why n = n is used to stop after the `p2(kx) = epp_rfc(ipp,k)` and check the final result on each itteration. After it when this code comes:

```
if (cmult.gt.0.) then
    n = n
endif
```

is used for convenience (again you cannot stop at endif or else) purposes and yes this is kind of conditional breakpoint. But n = n is again used because you cannot stop **after** checking `if (cmult.gt.0.)` - you can stop **at it** but **not after** it - the next instruction will be after the outer if else. I hope this makes sense.

**Edit**: If it still doesn't make too much sense here is additional info: in order to check the value of `p2(kx)` after `p2(kx) = epp_rfc(ipp,k)` has executed the debugger has to emit instructions to check/fetch it - hence it is required to know  a) what is the size of `p2(kx)` b) it's location - remember the last instruction(s)! and c) emit the appropriate instructions to fetch the value  `p2(kx)`. All to complicated for the debugger as this is actually logic - the debugger has to be 'smart' (falls into AI domain), if a debugger could do this Terminator would have existed by now.